# Xcode 4 too many clang processes

Tags: xcode, xcode4

With references to the following question [speeding up xcode builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208926/how-to-speedup-xcode-builds-without-any-project-modifications), the following command still works in Xcode 4:

> defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks 4

However it only limits the number of 'cplus' processes that Xcode initiates while building. In Xcode 4 now I also get a ton (more than the number of cores I have) of the 'clang' processes, which eat up a lot of memory and freeze my system. So is there any way to limit the number of 'clang' processes while building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/545348#545348

> defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode
>   IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 4

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me in Xcode5, having the same issue (freezes on archiving on last file) is to change the Build Settings:  Set "optimisation level" for RELEASE (or all) to NONE. worked wonders.